# What string type is used in SQLite3 queries in Swift?

Tags: swift, sqlite

I am relatively new to Swift but I am writing a program that requires me to alter SQL tables using SQLite3. I would like to write a function that can create new entries based on given information so that I can use it in multiple instances across my project but I keep getting errors when trying to run the code in this way.

After looking into it, I am pretty sure it has to do with the string type of the first bind statement or the type of bind statement itself but I am unsure of how to fix it, and googling has not been helpful thus far.

This is the swift code I currently have (minus the handling of errors for simplicity):

```
    func create(table: String, newValue: String) -> Int {

    var statement: OpaquePointer!
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, "INSERT INTO ? (name) VALUES (?)", -1, &statement, nil)
    
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, NSString(string: table).utf8String, -1, nil)
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, NSString(string: newValue).utf8String, -1, nil)
    
    sqlite3_step(statement)
    
    sqlite3_finalize(statement)
    return Int(sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database))
}
```

Comment: I haven't used this library much but are you sure you can bind the table name in your query? Normally this is used only for parameter values so I wonder if it is the case here.

Comment: The answers here are correct, and your problem is almost certainly the fact that you can't bind table names. But also, you don't need `NSString(string: table).utf8String`. You can just use `table` and Swift will automatically do the string bridging for you.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the "string type".

This

```
INSERT INTO ? (name) VALUES (?)
```

can never work. You cannot parameterize table names. You can only parameterize data. Table names are code, not data. They must be hard-coded.

If you end up in a situation where you want to parameterize table names, you have exceedingly likely found a design flaw in your database, and you really wanted to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO that_table (category, name) VALUES (?, ?)
```

Comment: You're right! I just realized that one table has more parameters than I realized so I cannot use functionality like this. Thank you!!